# actualizar listview personalizado despues de borrar

Tags: android-fragment, android-listview

Estoy realizando un proyecto en android studio, donde a partir de un grupo de spinner que se llenan de un webservice, llenan una tabla que alimenta un listview personalizado mediante un adapter. Hasta este punto funciona correctamente, habilite el borrado de los datos desde una imagen que se encuentra dentro de cada conjunto de datos del listview, el proceso de borrado se realiza correctamente enviando la consulta al webservice, el problema comienza cuando quiero actualizar el listview despues de borrar.

**ProgCarteleraFragment**

```
public class ProgCarteleraFragment extends Fragment implements Response.ErrorListener, Response.Listener<JSONObject> {

    private RecyclerView recyclerCartelera;
    private ArrayList<Cartelera> listaCartelera;

    private AsyncHttpClient cartelera;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        listaCartelera=new ArrayList<>();
        recyclerCartelera=view.findViewById (R.id.idRecyclerCartelera);
        recyclerCartelera.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager (getActivity ()));


    }



    private void inicio() {
           leercartelera();
    }


    public void leercartelera() {

        String ip=getString(R.string.ip);
        String url = ip + "apk/llenarcartelera";

        cartelera=new AsyncHttpClient ();
        RequestParams params=new RequestParams ();
        try {
            params.put ("id_ueb", sharedpreferences.getString("ueb_usuario",""));
            params.setUseJsonStreamer (true);
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

//        Log.i (TAG, "ID_ueb para mostrar cartelera: " + params);

        cartelera.post (this.getActivity ( ), url, params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler ( ) {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
                if (statusCode==200){
//                    Log.i ( TAG,"Status:  " + statusCode);

                    cargarCartelera(new String (responseBody));

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {

            }
        });
    }

    public void cargarCartelera(String s) {

        Cartelera cartelera=null;

        ArrayList <Cartelera> listaCartelera = new ArrayList<Cartelera>();


        try {
            JSONArray jsonArreglo = new JSONArray (s);
            Log.i (TAG,"jsonArreglo Cartelera: "+  jsonArreglo);

            for (int i=0;i<jsonArreglo.length();i++){
                cartelera= new Cartelera ();
                JSONObject jsonObject=null;
                jsonObject=jsonArreglo.getJSONObject(i);
                cartelera.setLugar (jsonObject.optString("lugar"));
                cartelera.setDia (jsonObject.optString("dia"));
                cartelera.setGrupo (jsonObject.optString("grupo"));
                cartelera.setImagen (jsonObject.optString("imagen"));
                cartelera.setGenero (jsonObject.optString ("nombre_genero"));
                cartelera.setFecha (jsonObject.optString ("fecha"));
                cartelera.setId (jsonObject.getString ("id"));

                String hora=jsonObject.optString ("horario");
                switch (hora){
                    case "1": cartelera.setHora(jsonObject.optString("hora1"));
                        break;
                    case "2": cartelera.setHora(jsonObject.optString("hora2"));
                        break;
                    case "4": cartelera.setHora(jsonObject.optString("hora3"));
                        break;
                    case "3": cartelera.setHora("Matinee Larga");
                        break;
                }

                listaCartelera.add(cartelera);
            }
            pDialog.hide();
            CarteleraAdapter adapter=new CarteleraAdapter(listaCartelera);
            recyclerCartelera.setAdapter(adapter);




        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace ();
        }
    }
```

**CarteleraAdapter**

```
public class CarteleraAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CarteleraAdapter.CarteleraHolder> {

    private static final String TAG = "ProgCartelera";
    private ArrayList<Cartelera> listCartelera;
    private  View.OnClickListener listener;
    public CircleImageView circleImageView;
    private Context context;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    public CarteleraAdapter(ArrayList<Cartelera> listCartelera ){
        this.listCartelera=listCartelera;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public CarteleraHolder onCreateViewHolder( ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_list_programacion,null,false);

        return new CarteleraHolder(view);
    }



    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CarteleraHolder carteleraHolder, int position) {

        String grupo = listCartelera.get(position).getGrupo();
        String ultimo = grupo.substring(grupo.length() - 1);

        if (ultimo.equals(".") ){
            carteleraHolder.txtAgrupacion.setText(grupo.substring(0,grupo.length() - 1));
        }else{
            carteleraHolder.txtAgrupacion.setText(grupo);
        }

        carteleraHolder.txtCentro.setText(listCartelera.get(position).getLugar());
        carteleraHolder.txtHora.setText(listCartelera.get(position).getHora());
        carteleraHolder.txtGenero.setText(listCartelera.get(position).getGenero());
        carteleraHolder.txtFecha.setText(listCartelera.get(position).getFecha());
        carteleraHolder.txtId.setText(listCartelera.get(position).getId());

        String url = "http://mandr.dx.am/assets/images/" + listCartelera.get(position).getImagen();

        Picasso.get()
                .load(url)
                .error(R.drawable.fondocorto)
                .into(carteleraHolder.imagenGrupo);

        carteleraHolder.setOnClickListener();
    }

    public void swapDataSet(ArrayList<Cartelera> listCartelera){
        this.listCartelera = listCartelera;

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listCartelera.size();
    }



    public class CarteleraHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        Context context;

        TextView txtCentro, txtAgrupacion, txtHora, txtGenero, txtFecha, txtId;
        ImageView imangenBorrar;
        CircleImageView imagenGrupo;


        public CarteleraHolder(View itemView) {
            super (itemView);

            context = itemView.getContext ( );

            txtCentro = itemView.findViewById (R.id.txtCentro);
            txtAgrupacion = itemView.findViewById (R.id.txtAgrupacion);
            txtHora = itemView.findViewById (R.id.txtHora);
            txtGenero = itemView.findViewById (R.id.txtGenero);
            txtFecha = itemView.findViewById (R.id.txtFecha);
            imangenBorrar = itemView.findViewById (R.id.imagenBorrar);

            imagenGrupo = itemView.findViewById (R.id.profile_image);
            txtId = itemView.findViewById (R.id.IdCartelera);

        }

        void setOnClickListener() {

            imangenBorrar.setOnClickListener (this);

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            String mensaje = "Eliminando elementos...";

            String ip = context.getResources ( ).getString (R.string.ip);
            String url = ip + "apk/borrarelemento";

            JSONObject request = new JSONObject ( );

            Log.i (TAG, "Url para borrar: " + url);
            Log.i (TAG, "Id a  borrar: " + txtId.getText ( ).toString ( ));

            try {
                //Populate the request parameters
                request.put ("idcartelera", txtId.getText ( ).toString ( ));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace ( );
                }

            JsonObjectRequest jsArrayRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
                    ( Request.Method.POST, url, request, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                            try {
                                if (response.getInt(Utilidades.KEY_STATUS) == 0) {

                                    Toast.makeText(context, response.getString(Utilidades.KEY_MESSAGE), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    swapDataSet(listCartelera);

                                }else{
                                    Toast.makeText(context, response.getString(Utilidades.KEY_MESSAGE), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    Log.i (TAG, "elemento borrado: " + txtId.getText ( ).toString ( ));



                                }

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                            //Display error message whenever an error occurs
                            Toast.makeText(context, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                    });

            MySingleton.getInstance(context).addToRequestQueue(jsArrayRequest);


        }



    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Rodolfo, la parte de código que compartes es muy extensa. Sería mejor si pudieras concretar y compartir las partes clave. De ese modo el resto de usuarios podrá centrarse en el problema concreto y ayudarte mejor y más rápido. Lee sobre cómo crear un [mcve] para más información. Saludos.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro borre cosas que no hacían falta para la posible solución, cuando se presiona la imagen de eliminar en el listview borra los datos de la base de datos pero no actualiza el listview mostrado, no encuentro la manera de volver a leer los datos